# bash script: add two statements with binary operator in conditional statement

Tags: bash, shell, binary-operators

I have the following bash script

```
i=1
while SH= read -r LINE
    do
        if echo $LINE | grep 'Network connection down!'
        then 
            echo "shutdown"
            exit
    elif echo $LINE | grep 'Network connection available'
    then
        echo $LINE
        ((i++))
    fi

done < <(tac /var/log/messages)
```

This script works so far. I am not an expert at shell scripting. I am trying to add an and operator to the first conditional statement, something like this

```
if echo $LINE | grep 'Network connection down!' && $i<4
```

Can anyone help show me how to make this work in shell script, every variation I have tried so far ends with various errors like

```
conditional binary operator expected
```

and various other ones that I can describe. Many thanks to everyone in advance :)

Comment: I think what you want is `[[ $i < 4 ]]`

Comment: like `if echo $LINE | grep 'Network connection down!' && [[$i<4]]`  ?

Comment: @lindsaymacvean: be careful of spaces inside `[[ ... ]]`

Comment: Yes, but put spaces around `<`, it's important

Comment: or `(( i < 4 ))`, if it's supposed to be a numeric comparison rather than an ASCII-sort-order one.

Comment: ...since `[[ i < 4 ]]` won't do what you intend if `i=39`.

Comment: thanks @AndreaCorbellini that worked a treat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shell programming requires a special command to perform comparisons, as the `if` statement itself does not work with expressions, only commands. In `bash`, the command to use is the conditional command, `[[ ... ]]`.

```
if echo "$line" | grep 'Network connection down!' && [[ $i -lt 4 ]]; then
```

You can use an arithmetic command `(( ... ))` as well, which allows a more familiar looking expression:

```
if echo "$line" | grep 'Network connection down!' && (( i < 4 )); then
```

You can also replace your call to `grep` with the `=~` operator:

```
if [[ $line =~ Network\ connection\ down! && $i -lt 4 ]]; then
```

( or `[[ $line =~ Network \connection \down! ]] && (( i < 4))`, but you probably get the point).

Comment: woops, sorry. Forgot we were talking about numbers

Comment: perfect thanks. my script worked with `[[ $i <4 ]]` does it require `((` parentheses when using `<` instead of `-lt` ?

Comment: Inside `[[ ... ]]`, `-lt` is used for integer comparisons and `<` is used for string comparisons. Inside `((...))`, everything is an arithmetic operation, so `<` can be used for integer comparisons instead of `-lt`.

Answer (score 0):

The "if" line can be written this way. I've changed "<" by "-lt" since "<" and ">" are supposed to be used with strings, while -lt, -gt, -eq and others are better for numbers.

`` if [[ `echo $LINE|grep -c 'Network connection down!'` -eq 1 && $i -gt 4 ]] ``

The execution of this part counts the lines with text 'Network connection down!', always one or zero. Then this result is compared to one (1)

```
echo $LINE|grep -c 'Network connection down!'
```